# Im making my own network tool but I ran into a roadblock with my ssh feature. How is this fixable?

Tags: python, sockets, ssh, paramiko, network-tools

I'm making my own network tool and I am implementing an ssh option to ssh to a server but when I test it with an ssh server I got online, I can enter and ssh into it but when I run commands ex: ls, mkdir, etc. I just get an empty bracket as output. The output looks like this: "[]". Literally that's the output I get instead of actually executing the commands I want. How can I fix this???

pyNet code:

```
import socket
import time
import urllib
import pyfiglet
import paramiko
import ipaddress
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import scapy.all as scapy
from datetime import datetime

# banner
print("*" * 100)
ascii_banner = pyfiglet.figlet_format("ALL IN ONE")
print(ascii_banner)
print("*" * 100)


# ping host
def ping(host):
    res = os.system("ping -c 10 " + host)

    if res == 0:
        print("")
        print("Connection is alive....")
    else:
        print("Connection is down....")


# scan ports
def port_scanner():
    print("")
    host = input("Enter website to scan: ")
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
    print("*" * 60)
    print("Please wait, scanning host", ip)
    print("*" * 60)

    t = datetime.now()

    try:
        for port in range(1, 65535):
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            result = sock.connect_ex((ip, port))
            if result == 0:
                print("Port {}:         Open".format(port))
            sock.close()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("You pressed Ctrl+C")
        sys.exit()

    except socket.gaierror:
        print("Hostname could not be resolved.... Exiting")
        sys.exit()

    except socket.error:
        print("Couldn't connect to server")
        sys.exit()

    t2 = datetime.now()
    total = t2 - t
    print("Scan Completed in: ", total)


# ssh session
def ssh_option():
    ip = input("Enter url: ")
    t_ipaddr = socket.gethostbyname(ip)
    print("Making connection to:", t_ipaddr)

    user = input("Enter your username: ")
    passwd = input("Enter you password: ")
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

    ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    ssh.connect(t_ipaddr, username=user, password=passwd, look_for_keys=False)
    command = input("Enter command: ")
    ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)

    output = ssh_stdout.readlines()
    print(ssh_stdin)
    ssh.close()


# menu
run = True
while run:
    print("Enter an option (1 - 3)")
    print("")
    print("1. Ping")
    print("2. Scan Ports")
    print("3. SSH")
    choice = int(input("cmd: "))

    if choice == 1:
        url = input("enter website url: ")
        print(ping(url))

    if choice == 2:
        port_scanner()

    if choice == 3:
        ssh_option()
```

Comment: When do you get that output? What are the sample inputs?

Comment: I get that output when I input a command. Example, I input "ls" and then the the output is "[]" for some reason instead of showing my files. Also I know its obvious but just in case, my ssh session code is in a function above the menu and I call it on option "3" in the menu.